# EOS 1300D not supported by EDSDK

Tags: edsdk, canon-sdk

I am using EDSDK for application and it is working fine with EOS1200D but giving not supported Error while calling OpenSession() using EOS 1300D

I am getting below Error

```
NOT_SUPPORTED Stack Trace:   at EOSDigital.API.STAThread.Invoke(Action action)
   at EOSDigital.API.Camera.OpenSession()
```

Comment: Which SDK version are you using? You need at least 3.4 to use the 1300D

Comment: I just checked its 2.14.0.3, How to obtain latest one any Idea?

Comment: That's definitely too old. You have to go to the Canon site of your region and apply for it. For the Philippines, this would be the link: http://www.canon-asia.com/personal/web/developerresource/apply-digital-imaging?languageCode=EN

Comment: @JohannesBildstein Thank you very much for your helpful comments.

Comment: no problem, glad I could help!

Comment: error = EDSDK.EdsOpenSession(cameraDev);